# Alternatives to Artefact Animator

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, easing

I want to know if there are any viable alternatives to [Artefact Animator](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=artefactanimator) for animating object properties.

I'm asking because I see that the project is no longer supported and I'd like to know if there's a newer/modern alternative that does what Artefact can do and maybe more.

Thank you.

*Note: I did Google my ass off before posting the question here, I just couldn't find anything worth the attention, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Material Design

It is stacked with bunch of useful functions

http://materialdesigninxaml.net

To download it head to nuget manager and you will find it there under the name

Material Design

Good luck

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it is something. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @IneedHelp